# Powerbuilder Syntax. How can i use FOR i = 1 TO 3 loop in this statement replacing these numbers

Tags: dynamic, powerbuilder

CBX stands for Check Boxes , i want to minimize the codes using for loop but dont know the syntax for PB to recognize concatenations on statements

```
IF cbx_1.Checked = TRUE THEN
    fw_generate(1, cbx_1.Text)  

END IF

IF cbx_2.Checked = TRUE THEN
    fw_generate(2, cbx_2.Text)  

END IF

IF cbx_1.Checked = TRUE THEN
    fw_generate(3, cbx_3.Text)  

END IF
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You'll need to build an array of CheckBox objects that you can then loop through.  For instance,

**Declare a instance variable on your window**

```
CheckBox boxes[]
```

**Add code in your window open event to collect the objects you want to loop through:**

```
integer i
for i = 1 to UpperBound(this.control)
    if TypeOf(this.control[i]) = CheckBox! Then
        boxes[UpperBound(boxes) + 1] = this.control[i]
    end if
next
```

Note, you can use whatever logic you want to include (or not) a given control in the list.  Here I added EVERY checkbox, you might need to do more testing in the IF condition if you only want SOME checkboxes.

**Loop through control array to do whatever you need.  For instance in a button click event the following will flip the checked state.**

```
integer i
for i = 1 to UpperBound(boxes)
    boxes[i].Checked = NOT boxes[i].Checked
next
```

By the way, `IF cbx_1.Checked = TRUE THEN` is redundant... The `Checked` property is boolean, so `IF cbx_1.Checked THEN` is sufficient.